# handheld with windows embedded 7

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-compact

I'm a little new on Window Embedded Compact 7.0(WEC 7) so I have some question about it :

1- Is there any handheld device that runs with it? All I found run on 6.5 and lower win CE versions ( check this link please : http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-handheld-devices.aspx)

2- what's its .Net framework version? .NET CF 3.5 or .NET CF 3.7 ? I don't know whether its technology related to windows 7 or windows phone 7. If its .NET version is .NET CF 3.7, can I run my old .NET 3.5 apps over it or I should change them to silverlight version? (As I know I cannot run them on windows phone 7)

3-I couldn't find any screenshot of it.

4- For window phone 7, there is a free add-on on VS 2010 for development (although publishing is not free). Is there any free development toolkit & emulator(handheld emulator indeed)?

Thanks in advance

4-..or Completely I'm in a wrong way of thinking? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About your questions:

*1- Is there any handheld device that runs with it?* 

Yes [there are](http://amyuni.com/en/developer/devtouch). 
The [Windows Embedded Partner Program](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/partners/find-windows-embedded-partners.aspx) might give you more alternatives

*2- what's its .Net framework version? .NET CF 3.5 or .NET CF 3.7 ?* 

[Windows Embedded Compact 7 includes the .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486593.aspx)

*I don't know whether its technology related to windows 7 or windows phone 7.* 

AFAIK, it is not related to Windows 7, and it is not realated at all with Windows Phone 7.

*If its .NET version is .NET CF 3.7, can I run my old .NET 3.5 apps over it?*

The .NETCF version is 3.5, so yes, you can run your old >NETCF applications.

*or I should change them to silverlight version?* 

If you do that, then your application will not work anymore. WinCE 7 does not support managed silverlight, it only supports something that is somehow called Silverlight but it actually targets development in native code using C++.

*3-I couldn't find any screenshot of it.*

Here, enjoy:
[image]

*4- For window phone 7, there is a free add-on on VS 2010 for development (although publishing is not free). Is there any free development toolkit & emulator(handheld emulator indeed)?*

You can use VS 2008, but AFAIK it is not possible at this time to create an emulator for it, since Microsoft has not released the Emulator BSP for WinCE 7.

Comment: when was it released? It seems it should be a new release that it doesn't have any emulator and screenshot. So I get that its .NET CF version is 3.5 and not 3.7, am I right? anyway, the link you posted is a tablet device. Any other handheld(I mean smaller one,near to phone devices' sizes)? thanks in advance

Comment: Great thanks. I wish it supports more new technologies (like WCF, EF and so on...). Also there isn't any significant changes in its GUI.

Comment: If you use the new Silverlight C++ API with its new GUI shell you will indeed see a diference, but the lack of compatibility with previous code (.netcf), and the lack of documentation and tutorials is not very encouraging

Comment: surely I prefer compatibility to new GUI! As I see in your profile, you are Amyuni Technologies' member. Is DevTouch your single win 7 CE device? I couldn't find any other device(specially handheld) in your web site. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the only device the company currently produces.I added one more link to my answer, I hope it helps.